# What would cause a support post for a load bearing beam to bulge or shift?

Tags: beam, post, crack, support

Last year I had a wall removed (load bearing) and a 20' beam installed.  The end posts where it is supported are covered in drywall.  I noticed some cracks at a seam on the drywall (at a seam near the middle of the post) and was wondering what could be the cause of it.  Should I be concerned? What should I look for regarding contributing causes?[image: picture of crack]

Comment: If the crack is at a seam, then probably just normal setting, due to the major change.  I do hope that you had a structural engineer to design the changes.

Comment: wet building materials drying out and shrinking

Answer (score 1):

That crack is superficial.  It is the result of newer materials expanding and contracting.  Not at all uncommon this time of year.

If you would have seen bulges and /or drywall that appeared to be crushing, it would be a concern.   In this case I think you are ok.  Caulk the crack and paint and relax.